# Read a qual file from fastq and calculate average

Tags: average

I can understand a bit of bash and R but not enough to write sth.
I have taken the qual file from my FastQ file using PRINSEQ and I have something like that:

```
>R8ABE:00036:00036
20 20 20 25 15 25 30 30 25 25 25 15 20 15 20 20 25 25 15 21 15 21 21 26 34 36 25 25 28 25 25 21 31 25 25 25 11 25 25 25 25 13 23 13 13 15 13 13 23 26 26 21 25 19 25 19 25 19 25 25
11 21 21 21 21 15 21 21 29 21 21 15 21 21 21 13 13 23
>R8ABE:00038:00039
20 20 15 20 25 15 20 23 14 13 14 14  8 13 23 23  8 13 13 13 13 13  7 13 13 13  8 21 34
>R8ABE:00038:00042
23 26 27 30 34 15 25 25 20 25 25 30 31 33 33 39 39 16 25 25 25 25 25 12 25 25 19 25
>R8ABE:00038:00047
25 25 25 25 19 13 14 14  8 13 13 13  8 13 13  8 13 13 20 20 30 30 34 34 16 25 19 25 25 19 21 15 21 15 21 31 21 25 25 25 15 25 30 30 19 27 29 36 37 36 36 32 35 33 33 33 19 25 25 25
25 25 25 25 25 34 28 28 24 15 15 13  9 13 13  8 13 23 23 17 23 23 34 15 20 15 21 21 21 21 15 21 25 25 25 25 25 28 22 25 27 28 28 10 15 15 16 16 15 15 15 25 25 30 30 25 25 19 25 25
```

I'd like to calculate the average value of each sequence. The names after the ">" are not necessary. It's important for me to have these "means" at the original order, like a list, similar to this:

```
21.62
22.16
30.88
.
.
```

It does not matter if there are decimal numbers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python script like so:

```
from __future__ import division ## I'm assuming you're using python 2
with open('my_quality_file.fastq') as fh:
  for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('>'):
      continue
    scores = map(float, line.strip().split())
    print sum(scores) / len(scores)
```

For each line that has quality scores on it, it will convert to a list of floats, then print the arithmetic mean.